# how to change values of a 2d C++ vector by manipulating its slice?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, slice

my example code is:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void print_vec(vector<vector<int>> v) {
    cout << "**********print start!!!**********" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "**********print end!!!**********" << endl;
}

void change_vec(vector<vector<int>>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j) {
            v[i][j] *= 10000;
        }
    }
}

void change_vec(vector<vector<int>>& v, int pos1, int pos2) {
    for (int i = pos1; i < pos2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j) {
            v[i][j] *= 10000;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> block_values = {{99,98},{97,96},{95,94},{93,92},{91,90},{89,88},{87,86},{85,84},{83,82},{81,80}};

    vector<std::vector<int>> sub = vector<std::vector<int>>(block_values.begin() + 1, block_values.begin()+3);
    print_vec(sub);
    change_vec(sub);
    change_vec(block_values, 6, 7);
    print_vec(sub);
    print_vec(block_values);
}
```

The output is:

```
**********print start!!!**********
97 96 
95 94 
**********print end!!!**********
**********print start!!!**********
970000 960000 
950000 940000 
**********print end!!!**********
**********print start!!!**********
99 98 
97 96 
95 94 
93 92 
91 90 
89 88 
870000 860000 
85 84 
83 82 
81 80 
**********print end!!!**********
```

The modification from `sub` does not affect `block_values`. So my question is how can I initialize `sub` so that when I change values of `sub`, `block_values` also change? Thanks!

I compile this program and want: the change of the vector slice can "persist" on the whole vector.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Comment: You'll also want to check out [*Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/845568) and [*Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/845568).

Comment: sorry, we can only use c++11... but `std::span` is a c++20 feature

Comment: Then you'll likely want to convert your functions to take iterators as arguments instead of passing them a vector.

Comment: I recommend [ask].

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Thanks, in the real project we definitely do not use `<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`. Here we just for a quick display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `sub` is a copy of the range you want to modify. The unfortunate side effect of taking this approach is that once `sub` is modified the only real way to have those changes reflected in `block_values` is to copy those values back. Another approach would be to change your `change_vec` functions to work using iterators allowing you to instead work on a range of data. A nice benefit of taking this approach is that it opens up the door to also taking better advantage of the C++ Standard Library which is heavily rooted in the iterator model.

The following update to your code eliminates the use of `sub` altogether and changes the second overload of `change_vec` to rely on the first thus eliminating duplicate logic.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print_vec(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v) {
    std::cout << "**********print start!!!**********" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& row : v) {
        for (const auto& value: row) {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "**********print end!!!**********" << std::endl;
}

void change_vec(
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator begin,
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator end) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        for (auto& value : *begin) {
            value *= 10000;
        }
    }
}

void change_vec(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v, size_t pos1, size_t pos2) {
    change_vec(v.begin() + pos1, v.begin() + pos2);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> block_values = {
        {99,98},{97,96},{95,94},{93,92},{91,90},
        {89,88},{87,86},{85,84},{83,82},{81,80}};

    print_vec(block_values);
    change_vec(block_values.begin() + 1, block_values.begin() + 3);
    change_vec(block_values, 6, 7);
    print_vec(block_values);
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
**********print start!!!**********
99 98
97 96
95 94
93 92
91 90
89 88
87 86
85 84
83 82
81 80
**********print end!!!**********
**********print start!!!**********
99 98
970000 960000
950000 940000
93 92
91 90
89 88
870000 860000
85 84
83 82
81 80
**********print end!!!**********
```